# How do I prevent too long cell entries from slipping down / keep them vertically centered?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Basic question: In this tabular, the cell entries need to be placed in one horizontal line. This does not work for larger entries ("(x)" instead of "x"), even when choosing a smaller letter size. How can I vertically adjust these?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Based on the class scrreprt by "KOMA-Script", whatever that means. If that doesn't help, please try \documentclass{scrreprt} or one of the usual.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.11\textwidth}|p{0.165\textwidth}|*{16}{X|}}
\hline
Kategorie &
Ausprägung &
\begin{sideways}Bie \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Übe / Rei\hspace{1em} \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Uml \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Zus \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bev \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}War \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Gle \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bes \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Hot \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Fre \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Zus \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Ord \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Fin \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Uml \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bee \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bee \end{sideways}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{.11\textwidth}|P{.165\textwidth}|*{16}{x|}}
\hline
\multirow{ 3}{*}{\parbox[t]{.11\textwidth}{Betroffener Reiseabschnitt}} & Dieser & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ &&&&&&&&&&&\\
& Jener &&&&& $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & {\scriptsize $(\times)$} &\\
& Ein gänzlich verschiedener &&&&&&&&&&&&&& $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{.11\textwidth}|P{.165\textwidth}|*{16}{m{.0453125\textwidth}|}}
\hline
\multirow{ 3}{*}{\parbox[t]{.11\textwidth}{Betroffener Reiseabschnitt}} & Dieser & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ &&&&&&&&&&&\\
& Jener &&&&& $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & {\scriptsize $(\times)$} &\\
& Ein gänzlich verschiedener &&&&&&&&&&&&&& $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Related question: When searching for an answer, I just found the advice to use `m` columns. Is it therefore possible to use
`\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` or
`\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`
just for the second `tabularx` mentioned? Can one switch off the effect afterwards?

Bonus question: Trying to use `m` columns without `\renewcommand` failed due to the mere fact that I don't get my arithmetic's right regarding the third `tabularx`. Why isn't `0.11\textwidth + 0.165\textwidth + 16*0.0453125\textwidth` = `\textwidth`? (Doesn't work for 0.12 + 0.18 + 16*0.04375 either.)

[image: image of the problem]

Comment: `p` (and `X` columns are parboxes designed for multiline text with line breaking to the specified (or calculated) width, if your entries should be on a single line they are probably not the right sort of column

Comment: your arithmetic is wrong as you have not taken account of the 2\tabcolsep padding in each column and the `\arrayrulewidth` taken up by each vertical line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `(x)` comes on the next line is that you added a break point before the text with `\hspace{0pt}` and `(x)` is too wide to fit in the specified column width, if you change to

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{X}
```

then it comes on one line, although it is still too wide to fit unless you use a smaller font or use some other means to shrink the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Based on the class scrreprt by "KOMA-Script", whatever that means. If that doesn't help, please try \documentclass{scrreprt} or one of the usual.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.11\textwidth}|p{0.165\textwidth}|*{16}{X|}}
\hline
Kategorie &
Ausprägung &
\begin{sideways}Bie \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Übe / Rei\hspace{1em} \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Uml \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Zus \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bev \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}War \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Gle \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bes \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Hot \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Fre \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Zus \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Ord \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Fin \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Uml \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bee \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bee \end{sideways}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{.11\textwidth}|P{.165\textwidth}|*{16}{x|}}
\hline
\multirow{ 3}{*}{\parbox[t]{.11\textwidth}{Betroffener Reiseabschnitt}} & >Dieser & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ &&&&&&&&&&&\\
& Jener &&&&& $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & >$\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & {\scriptsize >$(\times)$} &\\
& Ein gänzlich verschiedener &&&&&&&&&&&&&& $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ >\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{.11\textwidth}|P{.165\textwidth}|*{16}{m{.0453125\textwidth}|}}
\hline
\multirow{ 3}{*}{\parbox[t]{.11\textwidth}{Betroffener Reiseabschnitt}} & >Dieser & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ &&&&&&&&&&&\\
& Jener &&&&& $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & >$\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & {\scriptsize >$(\times)$} &\\
& Ein gänzlich verschiedener &&&&&&&&&&&&&& $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ >\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick response - after hours of searching, I haven't thought the solution could be so simple! I keep those global newcolumntypes for means of hyphenating the first word, but can easily define the second tabulary as PPX instead of PPx. This works with documentclass tudthesis - and almost with scrreprt, would I have thought of getting rid of all those ">" from my first try to insert code here. Sorry for the mess, maybe someone with editing rights can clean it for a better overview for the future?

Comment: My only problem remaining is that the "(x)" entry is slightly horizontally uncentered - even though trying a C column with \newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} (using further packages ragged2e and calc). Any ideas for this?

Comment: @D.Duesen it isn't centred as it is too wide (overfull hbox warnings) you could reduce the font size, or make the column wider by for example reducing `\tabcolsep` so there is a smaller gap between the columns

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is it also possible to reduce \tabcolsep for single cell entries? I just need negative space for the "(x)" entries, for nothing else.

Comment: @D.Duesen if you use `@{}` between columns tabcolsep is not inserted, so you could insert something else eg `@{\hspace{2pt}}`

Answer (score 0):

The reasons of your promblems are well explained in David Carlisle answer. From this explanation follows that your table is to wide to be fit in text width as it is default defined in `article` document class. As solution you have the following possibilities:

- rotate table by use of `sidewaystable`
- increase text width of whole document by use of `geometry` package
- increase text width only for table for example with macro `adjustwidth` from package `changepage` and allow, that table protrude out of document text border

For the second case I select margin sizes to be 20mm, and wider text as `>$(\times)$` put in `multicolumn` environment with `tabcolsep` set to zero. With this I obtain the following:

[image]

with code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% <-- added

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}% <-- added

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}    
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{\footnotesize #1}}% <-- added

\usepackage{showframe}% <-- added for showing page layout
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{green}}% <-- customization of showframe

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}   
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{0.11\textwidth}|P{0.125\textwidth}|% <-- changed
                              *{16}{X|}}
\hline
Kategorie   &   Ausprägung         &
\begin{sideways}Bie \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Übe / Rei\hspace{1em} \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Uml \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Zus \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bev \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}War \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Gle \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bes \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Hot \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Fre \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Zus \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Ord \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Fin \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Uml \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bee \end{sideways} &
\begin{sideways}Bee \end{sideways}\\
\hline
%\end{tabularx}
%
%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{.11\textwidth}|P{.125\textwidth}|*{16}{X|}}
\hline
\multirow{ 2}*{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{Betroffener Reiseabschnitt}} % <-- simlified
    & >Dieser & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ &&&&&&&&&&&                                         \\
    & Jener   &&&&
              & $\times$  & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ 
              & \mc{>$\times$}% <-- changed
              & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ 
              & \mc{>$(\times)$}% <-- changed     
              &                 \\
    & Ein gänzlich verschiedener 
              &&&&&&&&&&&&&
              & $\times$  & $\times$ & \mc{$\times$>}   \\ % <-- changed
\hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For third case you need to add `changepage` package to your preamble as

```
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
```

and content of table environment put `adjustwidth` macro as:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{<changes of left margin>{<changes of right margin>}
... table content ...
\end{adjustwidth}
```

where the changes of text area left and right margins had to be select so that for above table local text width is 210 - 20 - 20 = 170 mm.

Comment: Thanks for those useful advices, but sidewaystable or landscape are not an option due to the table having more height than width. Increase text width is luckily not even necessary because of the ">" I forgot to delete during my first attempt to post code here (sorry for the resulting mess)! But I'll keep that advice in mind.

Comment: I suggest you to correct your question and add information  text width of your document. Knowing this information, I can adopt my answer. However, in my answer I indicate three possible solution and present one of them. What them you will use is up to you :-)